# What is the best pattern for array of status in non-relational db?

Tags: mongodb, non-relational-database

## How we can  change an status in an array of obj?

### What's the problem?

- I've and obj in db that have a array of object with operation and status:
  {
  id: ..
  stauts: ..
  info: ...
  operations: [{
   timestamp: ...
   operation: ENUM
   staus: ENUM (SHEDULE,RUNNING,COMPLETE)
  }] 
  }
- we are in distributed and multithreading context. (microservice)
- DB Mongodb

### Question: How we can change withouth race condition this document in DB?

If we read first the document and we check the status of execution we fail ever (in practice) we are in  a distributed context.

We have 2 idea:
- change the array in  an hashmap: good idea, in an map you can update the document ad atomic operation. But you lost compatibility with data in DB.
- Use the array as an **mutable** list with **immutable obj**.  In mongo (in general on the major non relational db the array operation excluding push and pull aren't atomic.) We can change the array in an list of state. toy pull the list of state, and in reading you can remove in dao the oldest or inconsistent data.

What is the best method ?

Comment: Can you describe what kind of update you're trying to do? Maybe I'm being dumb but I can't quite get what you're asking.

Comment: My update regards for example operation "a" changing status from "SHEDULE" to running

Comment: Where would a race condition come from? Mongo updates are atomic.

Comment: Mongo aren't atomic in array update. (is application side if i use not the positional update). the array can be changed in the time.

Comment: So you're saying you can't use the positional operator to perform the update?

Comment: Yes. This because first i must read the value for take the position but in the time someone can change the value in the time. I can use and retry logic with an integrity check, but i don't like this idea

Comment: "This because first i must read the value for take the position" - Can you _edit your question_ to provide an example of how you're doing this, because I think you might be doing it incorrectly. I do positional updates within a single call to Mongo.

Comment: Ok, thanks from some days i will provide the code.

Comment: See the `elemMatch` positional operator update example in the Mongo docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-embedded-documents-using-multiple-field-matches).